# How can I configure different worker pools using celery?

Tags: python, queue, scheduled-tasks, task, celery

I need to deploy a queued execution service with (generally) the following three classes of worker:

1. A periodic, low-priority job class that takes a long time and can be processed serially; these jobs should only use 0..2 workers in the system at most.
2. A periodic, deadline-sensitive job class that take a short to medium amount of time (say, topping out at 5 minutes)
3. An ad-hoc job class, that is higher priority than #1, but can interleave with #2. Any workers from class #2 that are inactive when this type of job comes in should handle it, without ever starving the pool of workers for #2

All three job classes are the same task, the only difference between them is how they're requested; they'll take the same input and generate the same output, but each one has different performance guarantees.

How can I implement this using celery?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Celery Routing](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html) to achieve your goal. What you do is setup three different routing keys and have multiple celery workers (with custom configs) listing *only* on the specific routing keys you set up.

Comment: how do you specify a worker to look for a specific routing key if you start a worker to a queue "celery -A proj worker -Q feeds"?